# ssh_exchange_identification: connection closed by remote host linux server to Mac machine

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to SSH from my linux server to Mac server. I did copied the Linux server pub key to Mac server authorized_keys file. We are using proxy in my linux server. It was throwing the error "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host". Please let me knowhow to check if Proxy is stopping SSH to remote server. I did ssh -v administrator@207.52.167.245 and below are the details.

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 62: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/sss_ssh_knownhostsproxy -p 22 207.52.167.245
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 1990977432
debug1: identity file /home/us-svclhjenkins/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-svclhjenkins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-svclhjenkins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-svclhjenkins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-svclhjenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-svclhjenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-svclhjenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/us-svclhjenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: you have given too much information publicly. "no such file" does not bother you? Give the keyfile location manually when invoking ssh and see if you connect.

Comment: "No such file or directory" is a perfectly normal thing to see there.